# Exception while trying to load data from database white EhCache bootstrapping process

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, ehcache, spring-bean

I am getting below exception when I am trying to load data from database, during EhCache bootstrapping.

If I do not load data from database i.e. remove `xyzTestResultFacade.loadxyzTestResultsFromDb();` from `xyzBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory` then everything is fine.

My guess is Spring's database transaction management is not ready while I am bootstrapping EhCache.

Please let me know if you think any other file is needed.

**xyzBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory:**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheException;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
import net.sf.ehcache.bootstrap.BootstrapCacheLoader;
import net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import com.abc.xyz.facade.xyzTestResultFacade;

public class xyzBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory extends RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory implements BootstrapCacheLoader {

    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(xyzBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory.class);

    @Autowired
    xyzTestResultFacade xyzTestResultFacade;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAsynchronous() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void load(Ehcache arg0) throws CacheException {
        log.info("Bootstrapping the cache.");
        xyzTestResultFacade.loadxyzTestResultsFromDb();
        log.info("Bootstrapping cache completed successfully.");
    }

    @Override
    public BootstrapCacheLoader createBootstrapCacheLoader(Properties properties) {
        log.info("createBootstrapCacheLoader log ################################ " + this.hashCode());
        return this;
    }

}
```

**xyzApplication-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- Loading the properties file containing the JDBC, MQ properties -->
        <bean class="com.abc.xyz.customComponents.xyzPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
          <property name="locations">
           <list>
            <value>file:${DOMAIN_HOME}/xyzConfig/jdbc.properties</value>
            <value>file:${DOMAIN_HOME}/xyzConfig/http_connections.properties</value>
           </list>
          </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

        <import resource="/context/web-applicationContext.xml"/>
        <import resource="/context/dataAccess-applicationContext.xml"/>
        <import resource="/context/cache-applicationContext.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**/context/cache-applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

    <!-- Process cache annotations -->
    <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" 
        p:config-location="WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" scope="singleton" p:shared="true"/>

    <bean id="initializingBean" class="com.abc.xyz.customComponents.InitializingBean" init-method="initializeProperties"/>
</beans>
```

**ehcache.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

    <!-- Sets the path to the directory where cache .data files are created.

         If the path is a Java System Property it is replaced by its value in the running VM.

         The following properties are translated:
            1.  user.home - User's home directory
            2.  user.dir - User's current working directory
            3.  java.io.tmpdir - Default temp file path -->

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/> 


    <!--Default Cache configuration. These will applied to caches programmatically created through the CacheManager.

        The following attributes are required:

        maxElementsInMemory            - Sets the maximum number of objects that will be created in memory
        eternal                        - Sets whether elements are eternal. If eternal,  timeouts are ignored and the
                                         element is never expired.
        overflowToDisk                 - Sets whether elements can overflow to disk when the in-memory cache
                                         has reached the maxInMemory limit.

        The following attributes are optional:
        timeToIdleSeconds              - Sets the time to idle for an element before it expires.
                                         i.e. The maximum amount of time between accesses before an element expires
                                         Is only used if the element is not eternal.
                                         Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that an Element can idle for infinity.
                                         The default value is 0.
        timeToLiveSeconds              - Sets the time to live for an element before it expires.
                                         i.e. The maximum time between creation time and when an element expires.
                                         Is only used if the element is not eternal.
                                         Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that and Element can live for infinity.
                                         The default value is 0.
        diskPersistent                 - Whether the disk store persists between restarts of the Virtual Machine.
                                         The default value is false.
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds- The number of seconds between runs of the disk expiry thread. The default value
                                         is 120 seconds.
        -->

    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"/>

    <!-- Defining the cache to store all static data -->    
    <cache name="refValueCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />

        <!-- Defining the cache to store all static data -->    
    <cache name="xyzTestResultsCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory class="com.abc.xyz.customComponents.serverCache.xyzRMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=false, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true "/>
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="com.abc.xyz.customComponents.serverCache.xyzBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"/>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

**Exception stack trace:**

```
<Mar 5, 2016 1:21:37 AM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xyzApplication-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/cache-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xyzApplication-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolvereference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/cache-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttrib
uteSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.An
notationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bea
n with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.Cach
eStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating b
ean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl
.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error c
reating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean prope
rty 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletConte
xt resource [/WEB-INF/context/cache-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAt
tributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.goog
lecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherP
ointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.go
oglecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSource
Impl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with nam
e 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; n
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have got some multiple CacheManagers (Hibernate maybe ?). 
Try to add a "name" attribute to your ehcache tag (edit : from ehcache.xml).

Comment: Can you please specify which one you are trying to point, I hv provided all relevant code .. I do not hibernate ..